# Images of list items repeats in html

Tags: html, css, listitem

The images of list items in dropdown menu repeats three times even though "no repeat" is added in html. please help me.

html code.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li style='background-image:url(images/menu2s.jpg)0 0 no-repeat;'><a></a>
            <ul>
                    <li style='background-image:url(images/sets.jpg)0 0 no-repeat;'><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li style='background-image:url(images/more-icon.png)0 0 no-repeat;'><a href="#">More</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>   
 </ul>
 </div>
```

css file

```
body{padding: 3em; }
.menu * { 
padding:0; 
margin: 0; 
font: 12px georgia; 
list-style-type:none;}
.menu { 
position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 10px; 
     left: 100px;
    z-index: 50;}

.menu a { 
   display: block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #3B5330;}
  .menu a:hover { background: #B0BD97;}
  .menu ul li ul li a:hover { 
   background: #ECF1E7; 
   padding-left:9px;
   border-left: solid 1px #000;}
.menu ul li ul li {
 width: 140px; 
 border: none; 
 color: #B0BD97;  
 padding-top: 3px; 
 padding-bottom:3px; 
 padding-left: 3px; 
 padding-right: 3px; 
 background: #B0BD97;
 z-index:50;
 }
 .menu ul li ul li a { 
   font: 22px arial; 
   font-weight:normal; 
   font-variant: small-caps; 
   padding-top:3px; 
   padding-bottom:3px;
   z-index:50;}
 .menu ul li {
   float: left; 
   width: 146px; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   border-top: solid 1px #283923; 
   border-bottom: solid 1px #283923; 
   background: #979E71;
   z-index:50;}
 .menu ul li a { 
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   z-index:50;}
 .menu li{ 
    position:relative; 
    float:left;
    z-index:50;}
 .menu ul li ul, #menu:hover ul li ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul li ul{ 
  display:none;
  list-style-type:none; 
   width: 140px;
  z-index:50;}
.menu:hover ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul { 
  display:block;
  z-index:50;}
.menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul { 
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 145px;
   margin-top: -22px;
   font: 10px;
    z-index:50;}
 .menu:hover ul li:hover ul { 
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 1px;
   font: 10px;
   z-index:50;
  }
.menu>ul>li:hover>ul { 
 bottom:100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent
 z-index:50;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Write it like this. You wrote shorthand in background-image rather than Background.

```
      style='background:url(images/sets.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;

> or

          style='background:url(images/sets.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 ;
```

> You have not given space between the brace and zero.

Comment: thanks for your reply, after clicking the menu dropdown button, the sub items are displayed but "menu" image disappears and then background color appears. i need image to be fixed. @wikijames

Comment: @DD. Thanks.If that helped you, i will appricate if you click this as answer.
The other problem which you telling. can you provide code of print screen that will be more clear.
Check the image path. Is it on hover ?